# Using Scikit Learn Support Vector Machine to make Predictions in Android App

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Basically I created an Image Multi-Classifier using Scikit learn but using feature extraction with a Tensorflow Neural Network similar to this blogpost:
https://code.oursky.com/tensorflow-svm-image-classifications-engine/

Training and predicting works fine in python, however I'm now trying to get this to work in an Android App and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I found a library for exporting Scikit learn models to java at: https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter
So this would probably run in android. The problem is that the SVM Classifier expects the 2048-dimensional input features from new images now and I don't think the Tensorflow Inference library is able to use a model for just feature extraction in an Android App like I did in the python code

Does anyone have an Idea how I could implement this feature extraction and classification in Android?

PS: I am using this approach because it seems to generate better prediction results than only using the InceptionV3 Model for classification like i did before in my project https://github.com/pirklbauer31/DiceTracker

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a project using Machine Learning on Android also and after have some trouble with using scikit-learn on Android, finally i am using Weka library.
Weka is other ML library such as Scikit-Learn but it is implemented on Java and have a .jar for use in Android:
https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android

I haven't used SVM but it is included on Weka's code and i think you can adapt it to your needs.

Hope this hepls you.